# VSCode: Any possibility to have a second, workspace-independent file explorer in the side panel?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am looking for a way to open files in vscode that do not belong to the currently active workspace (and should not belong to it, this is not about multi-root-workspaces).
The ideal solution I could imagine would be a second explorer-panel that allows to browse the whole filesystem-tree and open files from it just like the built in explorer.
Is there maybe an extension for that I haven't found yet?

Comment: It definitely possible to do something like that, the Haxe extension has such a view for libraries / dependencies: https://github.com/vshaxe/vshaxe/wiki/Dependency-Explorer However, I'm not sure if there's a generic extension for it.

Comment: I don't see any good reason to have such an extra explorer in vscode. Use the one from your OS, that's much more convenient (additional actions possible, additional attributes displayed, preview of files and much more).